# Append to end of string Ramda.js

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am trying to append a string to the end of a string using Ramda, but the following does not work.

`R.append("A", "B")`

it returns

`['A','B']`

Does anybody know a good way to do this in Ramda or in a way that does not mean I need to write code to curry javascripts `concat` function?

Edit:

I am trying to do the following

```js
props = {
    city: "Boston",
    state: "Massachusetts",
    zip: 22191
}
var appendCommaToCity = R.evolve({city: R.append(",")}
appendCommaToCity(props)
```

Doing `"A" + "B"` does not work in this sitchuation unless I define the function somewhere else and curry it, or define it inline.

Comment: "A" + "B" ??????

Comment: I have no idea about Ramda, but wouldn't [`R.concat('A','B')`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#concat) work?

Comment: Why curry anything? It's a one-liner: `const appendString = b => a => String(a) + String(b);` and `var appendCommaToCity = R.evolve({city: appendString(",")})`. And regarding currying. Tell me, would you ever use this utility function where you could do a simple `stringA + stringB`? I would certainly not. So why would you need to curry this thing if that's the only way to properly use it? Imo you think too complicated.

Comment: @Thomas `stringA + stringB` and `appendString` are totally different things. The first is just an eager evaluated expression. The latter is a lazy expression - you can call it once, twice or not at all, you can partially apply it, flip its arguments. And later on you can decide not to type check the arguments (as you did in your example) and only have to change a single function. Pretty awesome, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out, [`concat`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#concat) is the simplest approach, using either of these techniques:

```
const appendCommaToCity = R.evolve({city: R.concat(R.__, ",")})
// or 
const appendCommaToCity = R.evolve({city: R.flip(R.concat)(",")})
```

The first one, using the placeholder might be easier here.

But I'm guessing that your result is an intermediate structure that will later be used to join that city with the state.  If that's the case, then this might be overkill.  It's simply too easy at least in modern JS, to combine them directly:

```
const foo = ({city, state}) => `${city}, ${state}`
```

You can see this all in action in the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.0#?const%20prps%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20city%3A%20%22Vienna%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20%22Virginia%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20zip%3A%2022191%0A%7D%3B%0A%2F%2F%20%20const%20appendCommaToCity%20%3D%20evolve%28%7Bcity%3A%20flip%28concat%29%28%22%2C%22%29%7D%29%0Aconst%20appendCommaToCity%20%3D%20evolve%28%7Bcity%3A%20concat%28__%2C%20%22%2C%22%29%7D%29%3B%0AappendCommaToCity%28prps%29%0A%0Aconst%20foo%20%3D%20%28%7Bcity%2C%20state%7D%29%20%3D%3E%20%60%24%7Bcity%7D%2C%20%24%7Bstate%7D%60%3B%0Afoo%28prps%29)**.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log("A".concat("B").concat("C"))

console.log("".concat("A", "B", "C"))

console.log(String.prototype.concat("A", "B", "C"))
```

But just `"A" + "B"` is [a lot faster than `concat`](https://jsperf.com/concat-vs-plus-vs-join)